# Can I trigger events on select tags while them have the disabled attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select, eventtrigger

I disabled all the selects in the page with the `id` that ends with **_test** (and here all is fine), what I'd like to do is to show a `title` while the selects are disabled and the mouse is over them.

My problem is that it seems the `disabled` attribute blocks every event from being executed (I also tried with `click` instead of `mouseover`, but the result has not changed). In fact, I tried to comment `hide_children_option();` and the function worked.

So the main question is: can I disable the selects, but in the same time trigger events (or at least make what I thought real)?

Below the code-snippet:

```js
    function hide_children_option() {
      $("[id$=_test]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      hide_children_option();

      $("[id$=_test]").mouseover(function() {
       console.log("Hey you!");
        
        var attr = $(this).attr("disabled");
        if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
          console.log("This is disabled");
        }
      });
    });
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
 Official 1
    <select id="obj1_official">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Test 1
    <select id="obj1_test">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Official 2
    <select id="obj2_official">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Test 2
    <select id="obj2_test">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
    <br>
```

Comment: This isn't possible as disabled elements do not, and can not, raise any events

Comment: @Terry I tried to use `readonly` attribute, however it allows the user to use the `select` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to add a mouse event to a disabled input. However there are 2 solutions I can think of you could use.

1. The most simple one is adding a `title=""` attribute on the select and this shows a tooltip
2. If you want your own logic you could create a wrapper around the select and attach events to this wrapper. (take in mind that you need to adjust the styling of this parent to make it appear inline and you need to disable the pointer-events of the disabled select)

Examples:

```js
    function hide_children_option() {
      $("[id$=_test]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      hide_children_option();

      $(".test-wrapper").mouseover(function() {
       console.log('hey!');
      });
    });
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
 Official 1
    <select id="obj1_official">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Test 1
    <select id="obj1_test" title="Some text you want to show">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Official 2
    <select id="obj2_official">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Test 2
    <div class="test-wrapper" style="display:inline;">
      <select id="obj2_test" style="pointer-events:none;">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <br>
```

Comment: You can also add the wrapper at the same time as you disable, eg: `$("select[id$=_test]").wrap("<div class='wrapper'>")`

Comment: Well, your code is not exactly what I was looking for, but you gave me an idea to solve the problem: put `$("[id$=_test]").attr("title", "This function is no available.");` in the `hide_children_option` function. I implemented it and it works greatly, thanks for the support

Comment: I've added an update so the second solution works better by disabling pointer events of the select